# question on sets that I think is wrong due to the logic of A if B

Tags: logic

> Let $\vec x=(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$, $\vec y=(y_1,y_2,..,y_n)$ where $x_1,x_2, .., x_n, y_1,y_2,..,y_n$ are real numbers.   We write $\vec x>\vec y$, if <sup>†</sup> for some $k$, $1\leq k\leq n-1$, $x_1 =y_1, x_2=y_2, .., x_k=y_k$ but $x_{k+1}>y_{k+1}$.   Show that for $\vec u=(u_1,u_2,..,u_n)$, $\vec v=(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)$, $\vec w=(w_1,w_2,..,w_n)$, and $\vec z=(z_1,z_2,..,z_n)$, if <sup>‡</sup> $\vec u>\vec v$ and $\vec w>\vec z$, then $(u+w)>(v+w)$.

I think the question is wrong. This is because A if B doesn't mean A implies B but rather B implies A. And hence I can't find a way to solve this question and I think it is wrong.

Comment: This question is correct. You have to prove that $u>v,w>z$ implies $(u+w)>(v+z)$

Comment: can you provide a solution?I can't do it.

Comment: Do it in two steps. First if $u>v$ then $(u+w)>(v+w)$, and then the same thing to the right of the $+$ signs (which is the same because addition $a+b=b+a$).

Comment: There are two ifs in the question. Which if are you worried about?

Comment: the second one bof

Comment: henning i think your solution is incorrect.because here the definition of X>Y is different.

Comment: @LipikaAgrawal: Different from what?

Comment: How is + defined for these objects? I have a suspicion ... But shouldn't that be made explicit in the question?

Comment: I think you are not parsing the last sentence right: it is asking you to prove "**if $u > v$ and $w > z$ then $u + w > v + z$ where $u = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$, $v = \ldots$ etc.**" (It doesn't contain a statement of the form "$A$ if $B$").

Comment: this question is weird.I am assuming the definition of addition is like in sets.

Comment: The addition must be addition of vectors.

Comment: This doesn't affect the problem, but the quoted definition means that $x$ and $y$ are incomparable if $x_1\ne y_1.$ I'm inclined to doubt that that was intended.

Comment: Please give the ***source*** of your quotation.

Comment: which quotation?

Comment: ah! just leave it guys.I will try again later. don't bother.thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the first two sentences of the problem that you quote in your question comprise a definition of an ordering relation $>$ on $n$-tuples of real numbers (probably intended to be the *lexicographic ordering*). The third sentence is asking you to prove a property of that ordering (called monotonicity with respect to addition). To try to prove this, first write down exactly what you need to prove about $n$-tuples of real numbers by expanding the given definition of $>$.

Comment: The property in the second sentence is not transitivity -- read it again.

Comment: Whoops! Mind not quite in gear. Fixed.

Comment: The quoted definition is not exactly the usual lexicographic ordering; note that $x\gt y$ implies $x_1=y_1.$

Comment: @bof: your remark is correct, but it doesn't invalidate my hint: the point is that the OP needs to engage with the problem by expanding the given definitions rather than just crying "this is wrong" or "this is weird".

Answer (score 0):

> Let $\vec x=(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$, $\vec y=(y_1,y_2,..,y_n)$ where $x_1,x_2, .., x_n, y_1,y_2,..,y_n$ are real numbers.   We write $\vec x>\vec y$, if <sup>†</sup> for some $k$, $1\leq k\leq n-1$, $x_1 =y_1, x_2=y_2, .., x_k=y_k$ but $x_{k+1}>y_{k+1}$.   Show that for $\vec u=(u_1,u_2,..,u_n)$, $\vec v=(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)$, $\vec w=(w_1,w_2,..,w_n)$, and $\vec z=(z_1,z_2,..,z_n)$, if <sup>‡</sup> $\vec u>\vec v$ and $\vec w>\vec z$, then $(\vec u+\vec w)>(\vec v+\vec z)$.

**†** The first "if" is used for a definition.   When the predicate occurs, then we can write $\vec x>\vec y$.   Conversely, when we write $\vec x>\vec y$, then we assert that the predicate does occur.   And so it is $D := P$.

**‡** The second "if" happens in the form "if A, then C", so is $A\to C$ .

> Define $\vec x> \vec y ~:=~ \exists k\in\{1,..,n-1\}~\Big(\big(\forall j\in\{1,..,k\} ~(x_j{=}y_j)\big)~\wedge~\big(x_{k+1}{>}y_{k+1}\big)\Big)$
>
> Demonstrate: $\forall \vec u~\forall \vec v~\forall \vec w~\forall \vec z~:~\Big((\vec u{>}\vec v)~\wedge~ (\vec w{>}\vec z)\Big)\to\Big( (\vec u+\vec w){>}(\vec v+\vec z) \Big)$

Comment: yes that makes sense but generally,how will we know when which 'if' needs to be used?